# How to make table width extends fully when texts are just a few

Tags: html, css, gitbook

I am using Gitbook editor and trying to make all the tables (but each with different length of texts, that's why some of them can be fully extended while others shrinks) equal width in the same page. But when I wrote the following tags in the markdown at the title row of table, it still doesn't work out. Does anyone know how I may fix it? Thank you!

```
|<table class="fixed" width="100%">公關後勤組</table>|
```

The appearance remains unchanged from these tags and it goes like the tables in fifth item as in the following link:
http://derekya.gitbooks.io/disastermanagementmanual/content/zuo_ye_liu_cheng_v2.html

Answer (score 1):

in your style.css, you have this rule:

```
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

remove "display: block;" to get the table to its normal display mode and it will expand to fill the width as intended. new rule should look like this :

```
.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal table {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi Heidar, thank you for the clear guides. My colleague also pointed this out, and I have tried modifying the style sheet (for webpage) in Gitbook as this:http://imgur.com/K26GKkt...but it doesn't make a change either.

Comment: if you want to override it you should use this:
table {display:table !important}